# Use networkx to visualise a dataframe as an undirected graph

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to visualise a pandas dataframe with 28 columns and 40 rows.

I want to use the column headers as nodes and the edges should be based on the values in each cell. Each cell either has a 0 or 1, which indicates that this item has been used. An example can be seen here:

```
Shoes Dress Hat Pants 
0      1     0    0 
1      1     1    0
```

I know I can create a graph by individually adding each edge and node, but would like to automate it.

Comment: What should be the graph here? An edge requires 2 nodes, are the values of the index used as nodes? Should you have a single graph as output or one per row?

Comment: @msa What should the edges in this graph mean? Perhaps you want an edge between two nodes if they two items were ever have a 1 in the same row. Perhaps you want an edge between two nodes if they're ever the only elements to have a 1 in a particular row. You need to specify what you're trying to do here.